# ROS tango samples don't run

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I set up the Tango tablet according to the wiki
https://github.com/ologic/Tango/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Tango-and-ROS

and, after a bit of fiddling, got it to compile, load and build in android studio.  However, when I try to run any of the examples, android studio detects the Tango, starts to run and then fails "Error Type 3"
class {org.ros.android....MainActivity} does not exist.

But there is a MainActivity in most of the examples.

I suspect I am missing something obvious, but need some help figuring out what it is.

The wiki says that there is some documentation at:

~/rjandroid/src/android_core/docs/build/html/index.html
~/rjandroid/src/android_core/docs/build/html/javadoc/index.html

but the docs directory in that location does not have a build directory.  All of the other directories in android_core do have a build directory and went through a successful build.

Some progress:  By going to "run," "edit configurations" and selecting "Deploy default APK" instead of what was there, "Do not deploy anything" I was able to get a little farther.  Unfortunately, now I get an UnsupportedMethodException in both android_tutorial_camera and android_tutorial_map_viewer.

Specifically:
Unsupported method: AndroidArtifact.getOutputFile().
The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.

As per the instructions on the wiki, I am using android-studio version 0.6.1.
The gradle build messages show that "Tooling API is using target Gradle version 1.11"
I don't know how to check for the Android Gradle Plugin version (it should be 0.11 to work with studio version 0.6.1), but Gradle verision 1.11 is in the right range for Android Gradel plugin version 0.11

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199283/ros-tango-samples-don%27t-run/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2014-12-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the build.gradle files, located in the following directories,

```
~/rjandroid/src/android_core
~/rjandroid/src/android_extras
~/rjandroid/src/ROSTango/ROSTango/src/rostango
```

I added this to the dependencies  section:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
```

and that by itself fails, but when you also add

```
jcenter()
```

to the repositories section, the programs load onto the Tango and run.

I have no idea whether this will actually work, but if it does, then these seem like very odd things for the repo to have left out of the build.grable file.

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2014-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0